How to change the context menu of xaml designer in visual studio when developing a vs extension？
I need to develop a vs extension to edit the properties of WPF controls for some special need.
The first option that comes to my mind is to extend the context menu of xaml designer, and add a custom command in it. Does anyone know the guid and id of this context menu? (figure 1)
I have installed the "Command Explorer" extension, but i didn't find what i need in there.
I also tried Enable VSIPLogging in visual studio,but i still can't get the guid and id of this context menu.
The context menu of xaml designer
If this way is just not possible. There is another candidate can fulfill my needs. But I don't know how to start with that.
The second plan is: modify the "create data binding" dialog or custom the "create data binding" command.
create data binding dialog
I can't find the guid and id of this command or dialog either.

Based on my test, it looks like Enable VSIPLogging can not get guid and id for   context menu of xaml designer. About your second plan, could i confirm with you that you mean it can custom context menu of xaml designer by "modify the "create data binding" dialog or custom the "create data binding" command"?

No, my first need and my second plan are independent of each other.  If the context menu of xaml designer can be modified, my final requirement can be realized. If the "create data binding" dialog can be modified, my final requirement can be realized too.   @Dou Xu-MSFT

Okay. Again confirm ,the second plan:  do you mean you want to  extend the "create data binding" dialog for example change the dialog UI,  replace "create data binding" command with yourself scripts?

Yes, indeed. @Dou Xu-MSFT

Based on my test results, I can extend XAML editor context menu via id="IDM_XAML_EDITOR" but not for XAML designer. I find it is not support to get  GUID and ID values of xaml designe's context menu by  both "Command Explorer" and "Enable VSIPLogging". It seems they are limited to  menus on the Visual Studio menu bar and toolbars in the Visual Studio IDE.
